# A few slick sliders on the page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, slick.js

I have a problem. I bring out a slick slider with navigation in tabs on one page, I have a lot of them there. When I bring out one slider, there are no problems. But when 2 or more, all the sliders are broken. I think this is a problem because I have only 1 slider in the js file, and a lot of sliders are displayed on the page via php, and the browser thinks it's the same slider. How can I make it so that each of the sliders becomes unique and in js there was a check for the slider. I output php from Wordpress plugin Advanced custom fields. Help me please in this question.

My JS slick parameters:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

//Product slider with thumbs
jQuery('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 7000,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
jQuery('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: false,
  centerMode: true,
  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true,
  centerPadding: 150,
  appendArrows: jQuery(".slider-nav"),
  prevArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-prev pull-left'><i class='fa fa-angle-left' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>",
  nextArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-next pull-right'><i class='fa fa-angle-right' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>",
  focusOnSelect: true,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 901,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        vertical: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: 150,
        verticalSwiping: false,
        dots: false,
        swipe: true
      }
  }]
}); 
});
```

My PHP output:

```
<?php elseif( get_row_layout() == 'type_silder' ): ?>
<?php $product_gallery = get_sub_field('type_slider_gallery'); 
   if( $product_gallery ): ?>
<div class="product-slider-container">
   <div class="slider-for">
      <?php foreach( $product_gallery as $product_slider ): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $product_slider['id'], 'link_page_img', true )?>">
         <div class="fullsize-img">
            <img src="<?php echo $product_slider['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product_slider['alt']; ?>"/>
            <div class="subtitle-product">
               <h3><?php echo $product_slider['title']; ?></h3>
            </div>
         </div>
      </a>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
   <div class="slider-nav">
      <?php foreach( $product_gallery as $product_slider ): ?>
      <div class="thumb-img">
         <img src="<?php echo $product_slider['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product_slider['alt']; ?>"/>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?><!-- product gallery endif -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What does you actual **rendered** markup look like for the sliders? Can you post that please? It would help to see what your actual DOM looks like in case it's an issue with identifiers or nesting etc..

Comment: Using the **rendered** markup with your JavaScript please create a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using the code snippet feature. That way you can demonstrate the issue and it would allow us to help you better.

Comment: did you try to use the different class or id  for the different slider?